# Constructing and deconstructing records

Tags: f#

The msdn page documenting [Records (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233184.aspx) details `record expressions` for record construction and `record patterns` for deconstruction, the latter without naming them as such.
Here's an example which uses both techniques for an arithmetic operator:

```
// Simple two-dimensional generic vector defintion
type 'a UV =
    { U : 'a; V : 'a }
    static member inline (+) ({ U = au; V = av }, { U = bu; V = bv }) =
        { U = au + bu; V = av + bv }
```

This appears unwieldy and not very readable. For deconstruction, there are dot-notation or functions as alternatives. Since the dot-notation operator has a special dispensation in section 8.4.2 *Name Resolution and Record Field Labels* of the spec (`an expression’s type may be inferred from a record label`), there's normally no need to annotate. Accessor functions like `let u { U = u } = u` wouldn't give us any advantages then.

For construction, I think a case can be made for a function as record constructor. Access to the original constructor might even be restricted:

```
type 'a UV =
    internal { U : 'a; V : 'a }
let uv u v = { U = u; V = v }
type 'a UV with
    static member inline (+) (a, b) =
        uv (a.U + b.U) (a.V + b.V)
```

Is this an idiomatic thing to do? How to package such functions in modules and handle namespace issues?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: I don't think there is a general convention here at the moment so it will be a personal decision in the end.

To summarise what you get **for free** with records in F# is:

- Construct: `{ U = u; V = v }` (bracket-notation)
- Deconstruct: `let u = record.u` (dot-notation) and `let {U = u} = record` (pattern matching)
- Update: `{record with U = u}` (bracket-notation)

But you don't get first class functions for free, if you want you can code them by hand.

The following is what I would personally use as convention:

A `static member New` with curried arguments for record construction.

For update and deconstruction I would use some kind of [Lenses](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/a-little-lens-starter-tutorial) abstraction.

Here's an example of the code I would have to add by hand:

```
// Somewhere as a top level definition or in a base library
type Lens<'T,'U> = {Get: 'T -> 'U; Set: 'U -> 'T -> 'T } with
  member l.Update f a = l.Set (f (l.Get a)) a


type UV<'a> = {U : 'a; V : 'a } with
// add these static members to your records
  static member New u v : UV<'a> = {U = u; V = v}
  static member u = {Get = (fun (x: UV<'a>) -> x.U); Set = fun t x -> {x with U = t}}
  static member v = {Get = (fun (x: UV<'a>) -> x.V); Set = fun t x -> {x with V = t}}


let uvRecord  = UV.New 10 20
let u         = UV.u.Get uvRecord
let uvRecord1 = UV.u.Set (u+1) uvRecord
let uvRecord2 = UV.u.Update ((+)1) uvRecord
```

This way I would have first class functions for construction, deconstruction but also for updates plus other very interesting Lenses properties as you can [read in this post](http://bugsquash.blogspot.fr/2011/11/lenses-in-f.html).

**UPDATE**  (in response to your comments)

Of course they can be defined later, what does it change?
The same applies for the `New` constructor, it can be defined later but that's actually a good thing.
The accessor functions you defined can also be defined later, indeed any first-class getter, setter or updater value can be defined later.

Anyway the answer to your question is "no, there are no conventions" the rest it's a personal decision, which would be my decision and also many Haskellers are pushing to get some kind of automatic Lenses for Haskell records.

Why would I decide to go this way? Because in terms of lines of code the effort of adding a simple accessor function is almost the same as adding a get-Lens, so for the same price I get more functionality.

If you are not happy with the Lenses discussion please tell me, I can delete it and leave the short answer, or I can delete the whole answer too if it's confusing instead of clarifying.

Or may be I misunderstood your question, for me your question was about which convention is generally used to add first-class constructors, getters and setters values for records.

Composition is not the only advantage of Lenses, you can do many things, keep reading about them, they provide a very interesting abstraction and not only restricted to records.

Comment: While lenses are great to allow composition, I'm not quite following you on the benefits to implement them intrinsically when defining some data structure. As your [link](http://bugsquash.blogspot.fr/2011/11/lenses-in-f.html) demonstrates by way of extension methods,
they may as well be introduced retrospectively. Motivation for the question was a desire to avoid refactoring record definitions in wont of conciseness and readability. How will lenses help me with that, if you could bolt them on later anyway?

Comment: @kaefer I answered you in the UPDATE.