# What does the 'let {record} = object' syntax achive in F#?

Tags: f#

with the following example:

```
type Person = {First:string; Last:string}
let alice = {First="Alice"; Last="Doe"}
let {First=first} = alice
```

what does the last *let* do exactly?

Comment: It deconstructs the record via pattern matching (possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27804367/constructing-and-deconstructing-records ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last let binding is a binding with a [pattern match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching), specifically using a *record pattern*.

This creates a binding named `first` which will extract the First name from your record instance. In this case, `first` becomes bound to the value `"Alice"`, and is usable in that scope.

To illustrate, you can add the following line after your code: `printfn "%s" first`, and you'll see "Alice" printed.

Note that [let bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/functions/let-bindings) allow any pattern - the spec is `let identifier-or-pattern [: type] =expressionbody-expression`, which allows you to work with lots of different patterns. This is useful in many cases, for example, if you have a tuple:

```
let t = (1, 2)
let (first, second) = t // Use a pattern to bind each tuple value by name
printfn "%i" second
```

Comment: ok, I get it now; the syntax didn't appear obvious to me since 'first' comes on the right side of the '=', but it does make sense. Thanks!